# Создаю панель управления сайтом на php

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование, cms

Всем добрый день, может я дурак а может и просто делать нечего, но задался идеей создания панели управления для небольшого сайта, в целом функционал продуман, есть наброски решения разных функциональных моментов, но одно мне не ясно. Каким образом я могу при создании новости или статьи, прикрепить картинку? В целом все будет взаимодействовать с БД, все новости и тд будут храниться там, в теории можно было бы как-то загрузить через то же меню "создание новости" картинку, название и путь которой просто вставить в БД, для дальнейшего Echo через php. Интересны любые варианты, любые языки. Не знаю для чего, но прикреплю черновик функционала панели. Также понимаю что возможное решение где-то на поверхности, но все что можно было прогуглить я пытался, везде только готовые варианты, и поймите правильно, я не использую готовые CMS поскольку сама тема очень интересна, да и возможностей всегда больше когда делаешь сам (Ну или с помощью сеньоров Стака)
[image: Примерный функционал панели]
На данный момент в силах реализовать только пару вещей из задуманных, соответственно все что связано с записью в БД и последующего мониторинга для меня не сложно. Тут скорее отсутствует фундаментальное понимание как подобные вещи работают, например если я захочу прикрепить не 1 фотографию а целую галерею, это же должно быть заранее обозначено? Не стану же я в БД писать таблицу для каждой новости, ведь только в таком случае можно удобно и правильно безгранично подкреплять ссылки на фотки. Очень много что написал неправильно, прошу не ловить кринж, в данной теме меньше полугода.

Comment: Возможно следует загружать картинку на сторонние ресурсы, и писать в БД просто ссылку, если это так, то могли бы вы посоветовать такие ресурсы?

Comment: Сработал метод с уточкой, пока все описывал сам додумал, спасибо! Не актуально.